# Installing packages in native windows node.js

Tags: windows, node.js

I am trying to get to grips with node.js, this looked like a fun tut http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/how-to-scrape-web-pages-with-node-js-and-jquery/ but I have only got the native windows version of node.js and I can't find a way to install any packages.

I have also looked at installing the binaries using chocalatey, but my version of vista doesn't have access to powershell. However, I do have a machine running windows 7 that I can switch to. If it isn't possible to install packages on windows version, I will switch to that machine and work through chocalatey.

Comment: Look in the node wiki for instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you have the [node.exe](http://nodejs.org/#download) for Windows, npm has experimental support for windows. You can try [working through the README](http://npmjs.org/doc/README.html).

Otherwise you can [manually install packages on Windows](http://icewalker2g.wordpress.com/2011/07/23/node-js-on-windows-who-needs-npm/). You will need to manually look at the package.json files for dependencies if you are going with option 2.

I have never tried it, but [Scott Hanselman also has a post about getting node running on Windows](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/WebMatrixAndNodejsTheEasiestWayToGetStartedWithNodeOnWindows.aspx).

Personally I have found its easier to just run a Linux VM since Windows support is kinda spotty right now.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is if you have git properly installed, you can open a cmd window, navigate to the directory containing node.exe, and run this:

```
git config --system http.sslcainfo /bin/curl-ca-bundle.crt
git clone --recursive git://github.com/isaacs/npm.git
cd npm
node cli.js install npm -gf
```

The more complete answer is that I posted a guide on how to install Node on Windows [here](http://cedricdussud.com/2011/11/installing-node-js-on-windows/).  It also describes installing npm to manage packages.  Let me know if it works for you.